# TCP: Establish a TCP connection

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

I've read many examples on networking with C and I'm stuck. I can see that the TCP packets with the SYN flag are on the wire (with wireshark), but the receiving end (I've set up a virtual machine for testing purposes) sends nothing back, not even RST.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>


int establish_tcp(int port) {
    char *ip = "10.0.2.15"; /* Virtual Machine */
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddrin;
    struct hostent *host;
    int sock;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockaddrin.sin_family = AF_INET;

    host = gethostbyname(ip);
    if(host == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s unknown host.\n", ip);
        exit(2);
    }

    /* copies the internet address into the struct */
    bcopy(host->h_addr, &sockaddrin.sin_addr, host->h_length);

    /* specify port (used by TCP a layer above */
    sockaddrin.sin_port = port;

    /* try to connect */
    return connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &sockaddrin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("status: %i\n", establish_tcp(80));
    return 0;
}
```

It takes a while until the packets are timed out and -1 is returned as status code. How can it happen that the target machine doesn't send a reply? What have I overlooked?

---

I think I've figured out that it is *not* a setup problem. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. The virtual machine is a Debian Wheezy, I check its IP with `ifconfig`. I tried if the machine is reachable with `telnet`.
To escape issues which might be related to Virtual Box I tried to replace the IP with the one of Google, yielding the same results.

Comment: This is more a question about your network setup than about programming itself. Update the question with details about the environment in which you're testing. Most likely you're trying to connect to IP address which is not reachable, and there can be many reasons for that.

Comment: And probably you shout use something like e.g. telnet or netcat to connect to this IP/port first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem most likely is this:

```
sockaddrin.sin_port = port;
```

The port number has to be in *network byte order*, which is different from the native byte order in x86 and x86_64 machines.

Change to:

```
sockaddrin.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Comment: Good point. However, if it was simply about connecting to closed port of a random number, he'd observe `RST` being sent back. So either the IP is unreachable, or there's also a firewall involved.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now establishing a TCP connecting to Google on port 80 works. I guess I have to live with a timeout on closed ports?

Comment: It depends - normally, connecting to a closed port fails pretty much immediately (try a telnet to unused port on localhost). But there are also firewalls dropping the packages destined to unused ports, pretty common setup for various reasons - and that's why you have to wait.

Comment: Thank you, @CodePainters that's what my recent tests can confirm: I can establish a connection to Google on port 80, on other ports it just times out (firewall). I reconfigured the VM to use a bridged adapter and I can see that RST is sent.